# Asp.net Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to use bootstrap in asp.net project. The page looks fine but if you resize the page to mobile phone size its navigation panel is not staying in dropdown position. My code is as follows:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs"     Inherits="BootTest.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">

<div class="container">
<a href="#" class="navbar-brand">My Site</a>

<button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

<li class="active"><a href="#" >Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
<li class="dropdown">

<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Social Media<b  class="caret"></b></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">

<li><a href="#" >facebook</a></li>
<li><a href="#">twitter</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >google+</a></li>
<li><a href="#">instagram</a></li>

</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>

</ul>
</div>

</div>

</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</div>
</div>


<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
<div class="container">
    <p class="navbar-text">This is a test</p>
    <a class="navbar-btn btn-danger btn pull-right">Subscribe on YouTube</a>
</div>
</div>



    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

`<button class="navbar-toggle" **type="button"** data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">`

Answer (score -1):

In your code data-target attribute must be id of main navbar div element id '#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1'.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
```